# Angular 7.0 feature module router doesn't load if shared folder

Tags: angular

I've got an app in Angular7 (with a router) and a feature module "report" (also with a child router) and I encountered the following problem:
If the feature module I load is located in the subfolder of the app then everything works fine. E.g

```
import { ReportModule } from './report/report.module';
```

If the feature module is located outside of the app because I want to share it among multiple apps (e.g. `import { ReportModule } from './../../../../../Base/Web/features/report/report.module'` ),  then the routes declared in the feature module "report" are not loaded, although the module itself loads, because I can use components implemented in the "report" feature module. The same happens when the feature module is compiled&loaded as a `npm` package.

What I'm doing wrong? Can you please help me? I need to load the feature module and I don't want to have it located in the app directory itself, so I can share the module with other apps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Load your module in the main app.module.ts.

```
import { ReportModule } from './report/report.module';
```

under imports[] add your module:

```
ReportModule
```